# Find an example of these two sets, or do they not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Find two sets $A$ and $B$ with $A \cap B = Ø, sup A = sup B, sup A \notin A, sup B \notin B$, or state that these conditions are impossible to fulfill.

Would the sets $A = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : 0 \leq n \leq 1 \}$ and $B = \{ n \in \mathbb{R} : 1 \leq n \leq 2 \}$ work with $sup A= sup B = 2$?

Comment: Your example $A$ seems to consist of $\{0,1\}$, right?  So (being a finite set) we have $\sup A \in A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example:
$A=\Bbb{Q}\cap(0,1), \quad B=\Bbb{Q}^c\cap(0,1)$.

There is $A\cap B=\varnothing, \:\sup A= \sup B=1$ and $\sup A\notin A, \:\sup B\notin B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{\frac{-\pi}{n}| n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=\{\frac{-1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

$sup A = sup B = 0 \land A \cap B = \emptyset$